# stripe-laravel does not connect

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments

I am trying to pay using stripe and laravel but when i start the payment process this error appear:

```
GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException
cURL error 7: (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)
```

I was check the network to api.stripe.com and works fine:

```
[root@localhost stripe-reachability]# ping api.stipe.com
PING api.stipe.com (103.224.182.249) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from lb-182-249.above.com (103.224.182.249): icmp_seq=1 ttl=47 time=152 ms
```

Also i put here my php code:

```
        $stripe = Stripe::make('sk_test_blablablablabla');

        $charge = $stripe->charges()->create([
            'card' => $request->_token,
            'currency' => 'eur',
            'amount' => $price->price,
            'description' => 'wallet',
        ]);
```

Any ideas to solve this problem?

Comment: You can check the connectivity to stripe using this script https://github.com/stripe/stripe-reachability#stripe-reachability

Comment: Yes i did and the output is all ok

Comment: set verify peer and verify host false and try again

Comment: where can i do that @delboy1978uk?

Comment: where is your actual curl call code?

Comment: vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php

Comment: ok so guzzle handles it. where does guzzle get called?